# Prove K-regular graph with perfect matching using Dirac's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

I'm stuck on the Dirac's therom part:
Let G be a K-regular graph with 2k vertices. Proves that G has perfect matching using Dirac's theorem.

Comment: Hint: think about what you get if you delete every second edge of an even-length cycle.

Comment: @user771918 can't get it down as a proof. Its in my head

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is $k$-regular, with $2k$ vertices. By Dirac's theorem, there exists a Hamilton cycle:
$$(v_1, v_2, v_3, \ldots, v_{2k}, v_1).$$
Note that every vertex in $G$ appears (exactly once) in this cycle. Consider the set of edges
$$\{(v_1, v_2), (v_3, v_4), \ldots, (v_{2k - 1}, v_{2k})\}.$$
These form a perfect matching, as every vertex appears in exactly one edge.